# How does windows tell a program the name of the file which is opened?

Tags: windows, cmd

For example- When we open a .mp4 file, windows calls the default video player in the system, then how does the video player get to know which file to run after opening?

My guess is there must be a way by which windows passes the name and path of the file opened to the application opening it.

I searched the internet for hours but I can't seem to find a precise answer. Some answers vaguely suggested that windows uses some commmand line arguments to run non-exe files which applications (like the video player) are able to read. But still they don't mention which command line.

If any programming language is required to make me understand the answer, keep in mind that I have good hold on python language, and a little bit of C.

Why this question came to my mind-- I am  creating an desktop application which can open a custom file type created by me. I can easily open those files from inside the program, but they don't open the same way when a double click a file. Windows calls my app when I open the file type (I have associated my file extension with my app) but my application has no way of knowing which file was double clicked.

Comment: Usually the file name is passed to the executable as `argv[1]` like `C:\program files\player.exe C:\file.mp4`. You may see the exact command line issued by the system in the "Process" tab of task manager. (You may need to select the according field in the "View" menu.)

Comment: So, checking if `sys.argv[1]` exists would be enough or should i check that if `sys.argv[1]` endswith my extension or not?

Comment: You could do whatever checks you want. Even a matched extension may not be your desired format. Extensions are just for human.

Comment: Take a look in the registry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad.exe\shell\open\command`. this is the command that will be used to open a `NOTEPAD.EXE` targeted file.

Comment: See the two commands `assoc /?` and `ftype /?`. The first assigns a "type" for a certain extension, the second "translates"  that type to a command line. For example `assoc .txt` assings the type "txtfile" to `.txt` extensions, and `ftype txtfile` binds it to notepad.exe (per default - it may be different in your system)

Comment: For example `ftype txtfile` gives `txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1`, where `%1` (the first parameter) is your clicked filename.

Comment: @dibery come on man, if I am building a whole desktop application you should expect that I knew that file types are just for letting windows know which program to call to open the file .I am just asking if it is possible for `sys.argv[1]` to store another argument except for the opened file. Like -c or -d